# Story Identification: A Comic Book from 1970s about a Criminal trapped in Endless series of Rooms

Tags: story-identification, comics

I'm trying to find a comic book story I read in the 1970s.

It involved a criminal who kills a guy in, I think, the back room of the guy's store.  It might have been a barbershop.

For some reason the killer decides to go into another back room to escape.  Once he goes inside, the door closes behind him and locks.  There is another door.

The same process repeats endlessly.  He is trapped in a never-ending succession of rooms.

By the way, although they are similar, this story is not a reprint of "Don't Close the Door!" (which took place in a lost castle of some sort, but had a similar killer-stuck-in-endless-rooms ending).  Thanks for any insights.